# Should new users be able to embed images in questions?

Tags: feature-request, new-users

New users find us because they have a bike problem they need to get fixed. When they create an account they have a have a single reputation point, which prevents them from embedding pictures in their question posts.

Often, new users don't have the vocabulary to describe their problem clearly. Photos are then called for in comments. Sometimes the new user can provide a link to photos somewhere else and a helpful community member edits them into the question.

Wouldn't it be better to let new users embed pictures straight away? Does Stack Exchange permit this for individual communities?

Answer (score 10):

New users *can* embed images in a post.  I just checked by creating a new user (using an alternate browser and e-mail address that has never been used on SE before) and creating a question containing an image.  My new user has 1 point of reputation, but is able to add images.  Note that [at 10 reputation](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user) the "Remove new user restrictions" lists posting *more* links and doesn't mention images at all.

I suspect that the issue is more that new users don't know *how* to successfully include an image so it shows properly.

Comment: Note there are reasons that a user might not be able to upload _a particular_ image;  most obviously there's a 2MiB limit for uploaded photos and a lot of cameras will take images bigger than that if they're not reduced in size.

Comment: It could also be...... It's a major pain in the rear to upload images from the SE APP, it should be easier from an APP but due to SE not maintaining their own APP it's almost impossible. It's far easier to create the question then edit the images later on a desktop

Comment: To clarify, only a few sites, [such as Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500/1478931), disable the ability for users who don't yet have the "remove new user restrictions" privilege to embed uploaded images in their posts (in which case they're automatically converted to links instead). On most sites, low-rep users can embed images in their posts as usual. (There was a time when that restriction was applied network-wide, but [that was changed in 2013](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/195927/335251).)